# How can I include my custom user control with its custom view model into my xaml view?

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, prism

I'd have a little question on prism / xaml in general. If someone has a clue, I'd be happy to know about it.

I made up a standard Prism application with a Prism module (Prism 6.3.0). There I have a main view consisting of the following code:

```
<!-- MainView.xaml -->
<UserControl prism:ViewModelLocator.AutoWireViewModel="True"
             ...>
[...]
    <dxb:BarManager>
        [...]
            <local:MyUserControl/>
        [...]
    </dxb:BarManager>
</UserControl>
```

In that view, you notice

```
<local:MyUserControl/>
```

That thing is implemented as follows:

```
<!-- MyUserControl.xaml -->

<dxr:RibbonPageGroup x:Class="MyUserControl" ...>
    [...]

    <dxb:BarButtonItem Content="Import"
                       Command="{Binding ImportDataCommand}" />
    [...]
</dxr:RibbonPageGroup>
```

and

```
// MyUserControl.xaml.cs
public partial class MyUserControl
{
    public MyUserControl()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }
}
```

Now, the idea is that `MyUserControl` uses its own view model, because it needs to contain special logic related to that particular control. All that logic is defined by an interface `IMyUserControlViewModel`, which I would like to inject into the `MyUserControl` and make it available as its `DataContext`. Of course, `MyUserControlViewModel`, which implements `IMyUserControlViewModel` and which I want to inject into the view, has dependencies in services. How can I wire that up? I tried many things without success. I am well-aware of [these advanced ways of wiring up](http://prismlibrary.github.io/docs/wpf/legacy/Advanced-MVVM.html#advanced-construction-and-wire-up) and [these basic ways of wiring up](http://prismlibrary.github.io/docs/wpf/legacy/Implementing-MVVM.html#construction-and-wire-up). My guess is that it is not possible because, in the `MainView.xaml`, we use

```
prism:ViewModelLocator.AutoWireViewModel="True"
```

Am I seeing that right? If not, how can make my idea happen? Is it possible to do without changing the `ViewModelLocator`'s configuration, as explained [here](https://prismlibrary.github.io/docs/viewmodel-locator.html)? In the project I am working for, they want to stick to automatic view model wiring for some obscure reasons. Is there a way to override the automatic view model wiring in the module initialization code? The module initialization code I am talking about is something like

```
public class MyModule : IModule
{
    private readonly IUnityContainer _container;
    private readonly IRegionManager _regionManager;

    public MyModule (IUnityContainer container, IRegionManager regionManager)
    {
        _container = container;
        _regionManager = regionManager;
    }

    public void Initialize()
    {
        //_container.RegisterType<>();

       _regionManager.AddToRegion(RegionNames.MainRegion, ServiceLocator.Current.GetInstance<MainView>());
    }
}
```

Comment: Can't you use `prism:ViewModelLocator.AutoWireViewModel="True"` on the ?`UserControl` as well? Then Prism should be able to resolve the `DataContext` for you automatically provided that you have registered your interface with the container.

Comment: I can't, because that would not follow the [prism conventions](https://prismlibrary.github.io/docs/viewmodel-locator.html#change-the-naming-convention) which are necessary when we do automatic view model wiring. For example, my viewmodel will not be located in the same assembly as the view.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As a general rule, try to go view model first, if you can, as it makes things easier and clearer.

So in your case,  instead of

```
<UserControl prism:ViewModelLocator.AutoWireViewModel="True">
    <dxb:BarManager>
        <local:MyUserControl/>
    </dxb:BarManager>
</UserControl>
```

do

```
<UserControl prism:ViewModelLocator.AutoWireViewModel="True">
    <dxb:BarManager>
        <ContentControl Content={Binding SpecialViewModel}/>
    </dxb:BarManager>
</UserControl>
```

with a `DataTemplate` that maps `IMyUserControlViewModel` to `MyUserControl` and expose an instance of the sub-view model from your view model. This way, you can use a specialized instance, tailored for the use case at hand without having to jump through loops just to please the `ViewModelLocator`.

Comment: Hmmmm that's interesting. I remember having seen that somewhere in the prism documentation and I thought I would give it a try and then forgot about it. I'll give it a shot, thanks for the suggestion.